# how to find two exclamation marks in outlook subject

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I inherited an old programming where it sends email alert

The only keyword that I need to filter from all the other email is two exclamation marks

Is there a way to search in outlook for two exclamation mark.

Here is the example of the email subject

```
Subject:!![Order Number: 12340001]
```

We have hundreds per day and I just need to filter the email with !! in the subject

Comment: Why not create a rule to move all e-mails with `!![` in the subject to a different sub-folder, then run the rule against the inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Open Advanced Find (shortcut key: CTRL+SHIFT+F)

Select the Advanced tab.

Create the following search criteria.

Field: Subject

Conditions: contains

value:!!

[image]